# Remove a wrapper function in IntelliJ IDEA?

Tags: intellij-idea

I have a foreach block that wraps multiple statements such as:

`$outputArr[$type . "_" . "orgName"] = urlencode($this->params[$prefix."companyname"]);`

Is there any shortcut handy that will just remove the urlencode wrapper, in this example, without me having to manually go to end of line, delete the end bracket?

**Bonus point**: Do it in one command for all the same repeating wrapping `urlencode` lines in the block :)

Answer (score 5):

For a single occurence, use the "Unwrap/Remove..." action (Ctrl-Shift-DELETE on Windows). (Place the caret inside the urlencode(......).

If there are many such occurences, I usually define my own method, that overwrites the other urlencode:

```
private String urlencode(String a) {
    return a;
}
```

Then use "Inline" (Ctrl-Alt-N) to inline all calls to the method and remove the methopd again.

Comment: Unwrap was nice and seems to do what OP wanted

Comment: For macOS, it is "⇧ ⌘ ⌦"

Answer (score 0):

Regarding this, I have 3 approaches, which I miss them all since I switched to Neovim -- that's like another world of text editing.

Back to IntelliJ, here are my 3 approaches:

#### 1. Multicaret (Alt+Shift+Drag)

If the lines are neighboring and similar, though for a single line this is in no sense easier, it saves time when the same operation has to be done on a lot of lines.

#### 2. Expand Selection (Ctrl+W)

Instead of getting to the end and delete the `)`, locate the caret in the part you want to save (like `params`) and click *Expand Selection* till `$this->params[$prefix."companyname"]` is selected.

Do a copy (Ctrl+C) and keep on expand selection until `urlencode` is also selected.  Paste it so the inner content replaced the whole selected part -- unwrapped.

It is long when described in words, but in action it's like `<C-W><C-W><C-W><C-C><C-W><C-W><C-V>` looking at the screen.

Faster than moving the right hand to another side of the keyboard and pressing `<End>` and `<Left>` and `<Backspace>`.

#### 3. Regex Replacement in Selection (With Live Preview!)

It'll be like selecting the lines and `<C-R>` `<M-I>` (which is `Alt+I` for In Selection) `<M-G>` (for Regex) and replace `urlencode\(([^)]*)\)` with `$1`.  Some (or most) feel that using Regex is creating a harder problem for an easier problem.

*P.S. I am on a Mac and I use `Ctrl+A` & `Ctrl+E` for Home & End. `Ctrl+P` & `Ctrl+N` for up & down, and `Ctrl+B`& `Ctrl+F` for left & right.  Feeling "handy" enough as my hands don't have to move away from the home row.*